# Calculate size of textstring in pygtk pango for text fill

Tags: python, string, width, pygtk, pango

I'm searching for a method to pre calculate the width of a text string with variable length with python gtk/pango.
 I want to use it for adjusting text size automatically fill a given space, for a GUI that can be displayed with different resolutions and the text of Labels or Buttons or whatever should adjust to the given resolution so the use the maximum possible Font size without braking boundaries.

I have a workaround now, but it is a slow method and i think there must be something better:

```
def ButtonSchriftAnpassen(self, AktiverButton, InBox):
    '''function to set up fint size of directory/category buttons to use  max. amount of available space'''
    if InBox == True:
        AktiverButton.show()

        GewollteBreite = AktiverButton.get_parent().get_allocation()[2]
        GewollteHoehe = AktiverButton.size_request()[1]
        MaximaleBreite = GewollteBreite
    elif AktiverButton.get_label() == "HOME" or AktiverButton.get_label() == "Hauptmenue":
        #print AktiverButton.get_label()
        GewollteBreite = AktiverButton.size_request()[0]
        GewollteHoehe = AktiverButton.size_request()[1]
        MaximaleBreite = GewollteBreite -(0.2*GewollteBreite)#* 1000

    else:
        GewollteBreite = AktiverButton.size_request()[0]
        GewollteHoehe = AktiverButton.size_request()[1]
        MaximaleBreite = GewollteBreite # -(0.4*GewollteBreite)#* 1000

    Schriftgroessenfaktor = GewollteHoehe * 1000

    TempLabel = gtk.Label(AktiverButton.get_label())
    TempPangoliste = pango.AttrList()
    XTemp = pango.AttrSize(Schriftgroessenfaktor, start_index=0, end_index=-1)
    TempPangoliste.insert(XTemp)
    TempLabel.set_attributes(TempPangoliste)
    AbmessungenTempLabel = TempLabel.get_layout().get_pixel_size()

    while AbmessungenTempLabel[0] > MaximaleBreite:
        Schriftgroessenfaktor = Schriftgroessenfaktor - 1000
        XTemp = pango.AttrSize(Schriftgroessenfaktor, start_index=0, end_index=-1)
        TempPangoliste.insert(XTemp)
        TempLabel.set_attributes(TempPangoliste)
        AbmessungenTempLabel = TempLabel.get_layout().get_pixel_size()

    x = XTemp

    Pangoliste = pango.AttrList()

    Pangoliste.insert(x)
    AktiverButton.child.set_attributes(Pangoliste)
```

It builds a temporary invisible label sets the parameters and shrinks it as long as the measured extends are bigger then the max. allowed size.

If there is some other function to get this "filling" of text i would appreciate to hear.

Answer (score 3):

You basically just render the string with pango and then get the size.

Example:

```
def get_pango_string_size(str, font_name=TEXT_FONT):   
    label           = gtk.Label()
    pango_layout    = label.get_layout()    
    pango_layout.set_markup(str)    
    pango_font_desc = pango.FontDescription(font_name)    
    pango_layout.set_font_description(pango_font_desc)    
    return pango_layout.get_pixel_size()
```

(Taken from http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Getting-string-with-in-pixels-td1944346.html)